# Problema funcao str_pad em PHP

Tags: php

Estudei a função PHP chamada `str_pad`. Acontece que eu consigo faze-la funcionar bem na maioria dos casos, porém..... quando coloco como caracter a ser preenchido, um espaço em branco " ", ocorre que simplesmente não aparecem os espaços, nem à direita, nem esquerda, e nem partindo do Centro também.

No navegador só aparece um único caracter branco, os outros são ignorados para visualização, apenas existindo no código fonte, pelo Inspector.

Veja bem, eu já tentei o `&nbsp`, já tentei via teclado, os códigos: alt+0160, mas nada consegui. PS: com o alt + 0160 no lugar de um espaço, até aparece uns espaços na tela, mas também aparece um sinal estranho que é "�". O código é bem simples, vejam:

```
<?php

    $nome= "Island Avenue";
    $novo= str_pad($nome,30," ",STR_PAD_BOTH);

    print("Minha nova casa, localizada na $novo é linda!");

?>
```

Comment: Testei no ideone.com e funcionou. Está salvando com a codificação utf-8?

Comment: Marcos Xavier, eu to usando o Notepad++, e sim, eu já salvei com a opção UTF-8 SEM BOM. Mas não consigo ver os espaços em branco, apenas um e os outros sao suprimidos na visualização. PS: usando str_replace() indicado pelo Isac, beleza, mas gostaria de resolver só com a str_pad().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O � tem a ver com a codificação e não afeta o problema do [`str_pad`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-pad.php). Pode corrigi-lo definido a codificação utf-8 que seria o mais apropriado ou até utilizando a codificação especial para essa letra o `&eacute;`.

Em relação ao `str_pad` lembre-se que em html múltiplos espaços em branco seguidos são ignorados, é esse o motivo pelo qual não vê o `str_pad` a funcionar corretamente.

Se trocar a letra do `str_pad` por outra letra qualquer, por exemplo um `!`, ora veja como fica:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para resolver o problema do espaço pode aplicar uma substituição para `&nbsp;` imediatamente a seguir a fazer o `str_pad`:

```
<?php
    $nome = "Island Avenue";
    $novo = str_pad($nome,30," ",STR_PAD_BOTH);
    $novo = str_replace(" ", "&nbsp;",$novo); //aqui substitui os espaços por nbsp's

    print("Minha nova casa, localizada na $novo &eacute; linda!");
?>
```

E já funciona como esperado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pode até conjugar as duas funções fazendo diretamente:

```
$nome = "Island Avenue";
$novo = str_replace(" ", "&nbsp;",str_pad($nome,30," ",STR_PAD_BOTH));
```

Comment: Isac, sinceramente, foi incrível sua ajuda, de maneira simples, usando a str_replace com [&nbsp;] Agora, duas dúvidas: 1) o [&nbsp] pode ser sem o caracter ";", né? Inclusive eu testei e funcionou, sem o ";". 2) Vc sugeriu usar o str_replace() depois do str_pad(), blz, mas vc testou o [&nbsp;] direto no str_pad pra nao precisar uma outra funcao (str_replace) ?? grato!

Comment: @Fernandes Sem o `;` está incorreto pois todos os carateres especiais em html precisam do `;`, agora pode funcionar dependendo do browser perceber o que estava a tentar fazer. `str_pad` diretamente com `&nbsp;` não funciona porque ele irá colocar os 6 carateres como pad. Lembre-se que a ideia do pad é um caratere aplicado várias vezes. Em texto `&nbsp;` são 6. Mas pode combinar as duas com `str_replace(" ", "&nbsp;",str_pad($nome,30," ",STR_PAD_BOTH));`

Comment: Vlw Isac, depois de muito pesquisar e ouvir algumas colocações por aqui, realmente penso que a melhor saída é usar str_replace() após o str_pad(). Só uma linha e uma função a mais, pois esta, str_replace(), aceita multi-byte, enquanto a str_pad() não aceita. Grato.

Answer (score 1):

O `str_pad` não funciona com caracteres multi-byte, uma vez que ele não adiciona todos os caracteres de uma vez só.

O código original do `str_pad` é exatamente:

```
switch (pad_type_val) {
    case STR_PAD_RIGHT:
        left_pad = 0;
        right_pad = num_pad_chars;
        break;

    case STR_PAD_LEFT:
        left_pad = num_pad_chars;
        right_pad = 0;
        break;

    case STR_PAD_BOTH:
        left_pad = num_pad_chars / 2;
        right_pad = num_pad_chars - left_pad;
        break;
}

/* First we pad on the left. */
for (i = 0; i < left_pad; i++)
    ZSTR_VAL(result)[ZSTR_LEN(result)++] = pad_str[i % pad_str_len];

/* Then we copy the input string. */
memcpy(ZSTR_VAL(result) + ZSTR_LEN(result), ZSTR_VAL(input), ZSTR_LEN(input));
ZSTR_LEN(result) += ZSTR_LEN(input);

/* Finally, we pad on the right. */
for (i = 0; i < right_pad; i++)
    ZSTR_VAL(result)[ZSTR_LEN(result)++] = pad_str[i % pad_str_len];

ZSTR_VAL(result)[ZSTR_LEN(result)] = '\0';

RETURN_NEW_STR(result);
```

[Fonte.](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/string.c#L5332)

Note a presença do `i % pad_str_len`, ou seja ele apenas adiciona um único byte, o que pode fazer restar um byte desconhecido. Por exemplo, se você estiver usando o `chr(160)`, isso é para Latin1 e não para UTF8.

No Latin1, o byte `A0` representa "non-breaking space". Porém a mesma coisa em  UTF8 exige dois bytes, sendo eles `C2 A0`. Se você cortar um deles, por exemplo, isolando `C2`, você terá um `?`.

---

Se quiser uma "versão nova" do `str_pad` poderiamos criar um `mb_str_pad()`:

```
const STR_PAD_INSERT_ALL = 4;

function mb_str_pad(string $input, int $pad_length, string $pad_string, int $pad_type, string $pad_encoding = 'utf8') : string {

    $result = '';
    $pad_insert_all = 0;
    $pad_inset_limit = 1;
    $pad_str_len = mb_strlen($pad_string, $pad_encoding);
    $input_len = mb_strlen($input, $pad_encoding);

    if ($pad_length < 0 || $pad_length <= $input_len) {
        return $input;
    }
    
    if(($pad_type & STR_PAD_INSERT_ALL) === STR_PAD_INSERT_ALL){
        $pad_insert_all = PHP_INT_MAX;
        $pad_inset_limit = null;
        $pad_type -= STR_PAD_INSERT_ALL;
    }

    if ($pad_str_len === 0) {
        trigger_error ( "Padding string cannot be empty", E_WARNING);
        return $input;
    }

    if ($pad_type < STR_PAD_LEFT || $pad_type > STR_PAD_BOTH) {
        trigger_error ("Padding type has to be STR_PAD_LEFT, STR_PAD_RIGHT, or STR_PAD_BOTH", E_WARNING);
        return $input;
    }

    $num_pad_chars = $pad_length - $input_len;
    if ($num_pad_chars >= PHP_INT_MAX) {
        trigger_error ("Padding length is too long", E_WARNING);
        return $input;
    }

    switch ($pad_type) {
        case STR_PAD_RIGHT:
            $left_pad = 0;
            $right_pad = $num_pad_chars;
            break;

        case STR_PAD_LEFT:
            $left_pad = $num_pad_chars;
            $right_pad = 0;
            break;

        case STR_PAD_BOTH:
            $left_pad = floor($num_pad_chars / 2);
            $right_pad = $num_pad_chars - $left_pad;
            break;
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < $left_pad; $i++){
        $result .= mb_substr($pad_string, ($i % $pad_str_len) &~$pad_insert_all, $pad_inset_limit, $pad_encoding);
    }

    $result .= $input;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $right_pad; $i++){
        $result .= mb_substr($pad_string, ($i % $pad_str_len) &~$pad_insert_all, $pad_inset_limit, $pad_encoding);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

> Isto exige PHP 7+

Isso é uma versão extremamente baseada na versão original do PHP, indicada acima, com algumas alterações:

Ele suporta multi-bytes, portanto você pode fazer:

```
mb_str_pad($nome, 30, "\xc2\xa0", STR_PAD_BOTH, 'utf8');
```

---

**Diferenças da versão original:**

*PS: Supondo que eu não inseri nenhum bug.*

- Suporte para multi-bytes:

  Ele suporta caracteres que exigem múltiplos bytes. Você pode especificar o tipo de codificação utilizada, incluindo UTF8, que é o padrão.
- Um novo "STR_PAD_INSERT_ALL":

  Você pode inserir toda a string, ao invés de "mudar um para outro", caso você tenha uma string com mais de um caractere (exemplo: "abc"), você pode especificar para que seja inserido sempre "abc", isto tem um efeito colateral uma vez que não é medido o número de caracteres inseridos. Para usar, basta que use `STR_PAD_BOTH | STR_PAD_INSERT_ALL`, mas isso não é necessário NO SEU CASO.
- Retorno em caso de erro:

  Mesmo em caso onde um WARNING é emitido ele irá retornar a string original, o que não é o comportamento da função original.

---

Comment: Inkeliz, grato pela explanação, mas confesso que, pela pouca experiencia com php, não entendi quase nada (rs rs). Mas o que deu certo mesmo foi a dica do Isac, ou seja, usar o str_pad(), e depois uma str_replace() para pegar os espaços em branco que ficaram ocultos, para torná-los visíveis, replicando-os por "&nbsp;" Ou seja, str_replace() aceita caracter multi-byte (&nbsp;) mas o str_pad() não. Foi isso que entendi. E usar o str_replace() depois do str_pad() é muito mais prático que criar uma funçao como a mb_str_pad() só para isso.

Comment: O `str_replace` substitui um valor pelo outro, ele aceita "qualquer valor". O conjunto de `str_pad` + `str_replace` tem efeitos colaterais. Por exemplo, na sua string "Island Avenue" foi substituída por ["Island&nbsp;Avenue"](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f353d23beca1a2cb81ab9ac6ebe41b66307a1b5a),  ou seja até mesmo o espaço entre eles foi substituído, isso não ocorre na minha função. Não é só "praticidade", essa função (que nominei de `mb_str_pad`) tem o "mesmo" comportamento da função nativa do PHP, com a adição de suporte ao caracteres multi-bytes.

Comment: Inkeliz, veja bem, olhando sua função, ela é relativamente bem longa, ok? Sei que deve  tem uma carga de segurança e tals, afinal, vc a fez pensando justamente nos efeitos colaterais, mas... no meu caso, que só quero preencher e VISUALIZAR, os espaços em branco, penso que esse "efeito colateral" que vc mencionou não chega a ser realmente um bug, ou chega? E se for o caso, não seria melhor criar uma função [bem curta] que pegaria o texto a ser preenchido com espaços e (continua...)

Comment: e usar: um str_pad(), depois o str_replace() só que esse str_replace() seria invocado duas vezes: 1a. até ó início do primeiro caracter != de " " ou "&nbsp;", e depois do último caracter (digamos) válido, até o tamanho da string com espaços ocultos, para depois juntar os dois pedaços da string original, e formar a string que vai para o result? ou seja, o str_replace() não pegaria os espaços em branco no interior da string de origem, ok?